# C# Synchronizing different time zones

Tags: c#, datetime, synchronization, timezone

I have an application on a server which is UK based.

Say I needed the application to run at the same time for different countries. For arguments sake say I needed it to send an email to a mailbox whenever the time is 7pm in various countries.

How would I be able to achieve this? At the moment I just have it running from the Task Scheduler at the specific time (which is fine for UK based clients). However, I would like to support internationally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store date/times as [UTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx), and then compute time for each locations's time zone.

Plesae see: [C# - Convert UTC/GMT time to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/c-convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time)

Comment: It's the second part that's the hard bit. Noda Time is not quite ready yet but soon it will be a good solution for time zone calculations in .NET: http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/

Comment: Ok so when storing the DateTime (when using the system DateTime) I should always use UTC. However, from my example where I am just using Task Scheduler and running the application at 7pm, how would I work out when it is 7pm in different countries for it to trigger?

Comment: This is pretty much what I had to do.