# How do I convert current system time in to UTC seconds

Tags: c#

How can I convert time of day to UTC seconds in C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert UTC/GMT time to local time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand correctly, you want to get the `second` of UTC? Try: `int nSeconds = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Local).ToUniversalTime().Second;` to get the seconds.

See [Converting Times Between Time Zones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769.aspx);

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but you *might* be after:

```
TimeSpan timeOfUtcDay = DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay;
double seconds = timeOfUtcDay.TotalSeconds;
```

For example, it's currently about 7:15 BST (Europe/London), which is 6:15 UTC. The above code gives 22573.6674426, which is just a bit more than (6 * 60 + 15) * 60.