# Format time in DataGridView to local timezone

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a process that runs on a SQL server that is set to Eastern time, when the process it completed we populate a table with the completion time.  I have a view that is currently being  used by multiple applications which displays the Date/Time of the process in different columns, since this is being used by other apps I can't change the view.

The query I use to return my process data is below and the Date/Time are being converted to a varchar on the server side - so it isn't coming to the UI as a date/time.

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A2.TaskDateTime, 101) AS TaskDate,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),  A2.TaskDateTime, 108) AS TaskTime
 FROM Task  AS T2
 JOIN Application_Task AS A2    
  ON A2.TaskID = T2.TaskID
```

This data is then being displayed in the UI via a datagridview. I am trying to format the time column in a DataGridView to my local time zone because the users will be in different time zones.

I have looked at [DataGridViewCellStyle.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format.aspx) and search SO and found [this on converting to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/c-convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time) but that is parsing one string. I can't seem to figure out how to apply that to the entire column of data.

I would appreciate any help and/or direction on where to begin with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I handle this in CellFormatting event:

```
    private void OnCellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0) return;
        DataGridView dgView = (DataGridView)(sender);
        // no need to add TaskTime...
        if (e.ColumnIndex != dgView.Columns["TaskDate"].Index) return;
        string cellValue = e.Value + " " + dgView.CurrentRow.Cells[dgView.Columns["TaskTime"].Value);
        DateTime dtValue;
        DateTime.TryParse(cellValue, out dtValue);
        DateTime dtValueUTC = TimezoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dtValue, "Eastern Time Zone");
        e.Value = dtValueUTC.Value.ToLocalTime();
    }
```

Comment: The data that I am pulling in it a string version of the Time.  The view I am using is returning the time as a varchar, so it doesn't know that the column is a DateTime field.

Comment: Could you return the datetime field as is (that is datetime). There after, at the client side where you have the gridview, you can use the Format property set to "mm/dd/yyyy" to "hh:mm:ss t". This would really help you for datetime values that happen between boundaries - for example, Aug 26th 5:00 PM Pacific time is actually Aug 27th Universal.

Comment: I can't as I said in the original question, I am using a view that is begin used by multiple apps so I can't change it.

Comment: I have changed the snippet to suit your needs. You can improve upon it. You might want to (1) add a line of code at the end to update the time cell with the changed value (2) add formatting to your DataGridView "TaskDate" ("mm/dd/yyy") and "TaskTime" ("hh:mm:ss t") columns - you can do this at the initialize section where you bind your DataGridView.

Comment: Also, at the initialize section, you might need to set at least the TaskDate and TaskTime DataGridViewColumns's name. Like - <yourDataGridViewColumnObject>.Name = yourDataGridViewColumnObject.DataPropertyName = "TaskDate";

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I think I got it working now.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure all your data is UTC on the database. This is pretty much the standard way to store date/time on databases. I learned this the hard way.

Dump this code into your CellFormatting Event

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value is DateTime)
        {
            DateTime value = (DateTime)e.Value;
            switch (value.Kind)
            {
                case DateTimeKind.Local:
                    break;
                case DateTimeKind.Unspecified:
                    e.Value = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime();
                    break;
                case DateTimeKind.Utc:
                    e.Value = value.ToLocalTime();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: I just noticed you're moving from EST to Local and noticed you can't change the database. I'm leaving the top function intact since this is a popular search result.

So add these lines **to the top** of the function above

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) //change this to your column
{
    String sqlFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"; //change this to the sql format
    DateTime parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(e.Value, sqlFormat, null);
    TimeZoneInfo tziEastern = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
    e.Value = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(parseDateTime, tziEastern);
}
```