# How to get real date(or time)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

In mvc3 application when I create new product, I want to add it's create date.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create( Product product )
 product.CreateDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
 ...
  return View( product );
 }
```

When I will deploy site to hosting, will DateTime.Now create any problem? Does it depend on user's computers time? If user's computer time is not correct,  product's create date will be incorrect..I need help about this, always to get real time. Or, advise other way, please. Sorry for my bad english..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/c-sharp-convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` will reflect the date and time on the computer that the code is running on (so, in a web application, the *server* time).

I suggest using [`DateTime.UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx) instead - this will give you a consistent result wherever the computer is (assuming the computer is correctly setup).

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar problem, This helped me too.. :)

Comment: Still this is not the actual real time. If the system has date and time wrongly set, it will be a false time.

Answer (score 2):

DateTime.Now depends on the computer it's run on. That means, if you deploy a web application, DateTime.Now returns a DateTime set on that server. It won't return different values for different users, because C# runs on the server-side and isn't affected by a client.