# Change ISO date and time to indian time zone in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, time, timezone

How can I convert a date in the following format to a date in the India time zone (UTC+5:30) using C#?

```
2012-09-13T05:08:03.151Z
```

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/c-sharp-convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-09-13T05:08:03.151Z",
                                  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssK",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Then

```
var indianTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime (dt,
                     TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
```

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid Date Time.I got that error in using this code

Comment: Not solve yet got this error DateTime pattern 's' appears more than once with different values.

Comment: I have a date field in this here it give me kind Unspecified how can i change it in c#

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("your current date string","your current date string format",null);
string IndianDT = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyy");
```

Now in your **IndianDT** string you will have your Date desired format.

**Edit:**

In my above code:

replace **"your current date string fromat"** with **"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ"**

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid Date Time.I got that error in using this code

Comment: please mention your 'current date format' string you used in my code.

Comment: Use following : DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("your current date string","yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ",null);

Comment: DateTime pattern 's' appears more than once with different values.

Comment: can you give me an example of what these s h t Z etc mean.... EDITED
can you please provide me some reference to support you answers... thanks dude, i appreciate your patience.

Comment: s-second, h-hour, t to specify time in UTC format and Z is to define zone as per standards. Did solution worked for you....???

Comment: No Again error - this time it was "DateTime pattern 's' appears more than once with different values."

Comment: Try this one : "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSZ".

Comment: can u help me in 2012-09-13T05:08:03.151Z this one come on which time zone

Comment: do google to get zone and you need to hchange a code little bit from "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSZ" to "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ". 

In dot.net fraction of seconds are denoted by fff not SSS which was mentioned in my earlier code.

Comment: I have a date field  in this here it give me kind unspecify how can i change it in c#