# Convert US-Style DateTime to local time

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-8, localtime

How do I convert US-style `DateTime` such as `5/1/2012 3:38:27 PM` returned from the server to user's local time? I am developing for windows phone.

I've tried

```
DateTime localTime = serverTime.ToLocalTime();
```

but the result is off a couple of hours. I thought `ToLocalTime()` will take care of the conversion to any timezone the user are in? Perhaps I need to get the user's timezone info first?

**EDIT 1**

I think the serverTime is in the PST time zone

**EDIT 2**

My timezone is GMT +8. I tried the following, but the resulting localTime is 15 hour behind.

```
TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
DateTime localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(serverTime, localZone);
```

**EDIT 3**

This result in 7 hours behind my local time.

```
TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
DateTime dateTimeKind = DateTime.SpecifyKind(serverTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTimeKind, localZone);
```

**EDIT 4**

OK I think I am getting there but not sure if this is applicable for all time zones. I think I still have to consider day light saving because the resulting local time is just one hour ahead now.

```
TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
double offset = localZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now).TotalHours;
DateTime dateTimeKind = DateTime.SpecifyKind(serverTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTimeKind, localZone).AddHours(offset);
```

But then how do you get `DLS` is in effect for a particular time zone in Windows Phone? `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` does not seem to be supported?

Comment: have you looked at this article.  It has a lot of useful information about ToLocalTime and time issues.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/c-sharp-convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time?rq=1 Possible duplicate

Comment: I what format do you receive the server time?

Comment: The DateTime format is US-style and in the PST time zone

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, the `DateTime`-object `serverTime` must be of the UTC-form - or at least know what `Kind`it is. Read all the details around this under the **remarks** section of [this page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

What does the time *represent*?  If it is a specific moment in time, such as the date and time that something happened, then you should update your server code to return the time in one of the following formats:

```
// ISO8601 local time with offset.
// get from DateTimeOffset.ToString("o")
2012-05-01T15:38:27-07:00

// ISO8601 UTC time
// get from DateTime.ToString("o") when kind is UTC
2012-05-01T22:38:27Z
```

It's really important that you do this, because local times can be ambiguous when daylight savings ends.  You must either provide the correct offset, (-8 for PST, -7 for PDT), or send as UTC.

There are very few scenarios where sending local time by itself makes sense.  If you think you have one, please elaborate about what the time represents.

Comment: The time represents the moment the server receives a string (chat message). Unfortunately I do not have access to the server to change the code there.

Anyway I ended up not converting  to local time but, get the server local time and calculate when the message was last posted, like `5 mins ago`, `2 hours ago` etc

Comment: @PutraKg - Be aware that you will have ambiguity on November 3rd from 1:00 AM to 2:00 AM, when the offset might be either -7 or -8 and you will have no way of knowing which one it is.  If this matters to you, then you should have a discussion with whomever is responsible for the server code.

Comment: If you are subtracting from server time, then you might get a negative value, or an extra hour (on March 10 or Nov 3).  Your code should be prepared to deal with the ambiguity, or the possibility of negative values.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the heads up. I will get in touch with them and ask how to best deal with this situation.