# How to handle Azure's UTC time

Tags: azure

So Azure stores datetimes in UTC. What is the best way to handle it if my system need to have timestamps in, say, US Eastern Time? Do I store them in utc, but handle just displaying timestamps by formatting them? Do I format/offset timestamps before storing them in the database? What is the best practice for solving this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always advocate for storing in UTC time as it is the standard time in which you can calculate any other times zone off of. This means if you have a service in which any one can connect to from any location, it is easier to either detect the timezone the user in currently in based on their system, or have them save the timezone they would prefer to see the time set in from your application.

[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices) had a very large discussion which talks about it at length, which you might be interested in reading to help make your decision. If you decide to store UTC and convert the time, here is a post explaining [How to convert from UTC to Local Time in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/963812/333730)

Answer (score 0):

- Storing time in any persistent store (cache, db, queues, etc.) - always use UTC.
- Time in User Interface - get UTC from your APIs (REST) and show it in the local system time (based on users' system).
- Additionally, application can have an option or user settings to make timezone configurable.
- Remember if you have multiple servers in a distributed environment, it is must to synchronize the clocks in all the servers.

Thanks.