# Timezone issue with UIDatePicker Date: 1 Hour Wrong

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin.ios, uidatepicker, utc

I'm having an issue with the Monotouch UIDatePicker being 1 hour behind. I think this is to do with Time Zones or something similar. I've tried explicitly setting the TimeZone and Locale of  my UIDatePicker but this doesn't seem to be helping.

```
datePicker.Locale = NSLocale.CurrentLocale;
datePicker.TimeZone = NSTimeZone.LocalTimeZone;
```

In the ValueChanged handler the following line returns a value 1 hour earlier than the time selected in the user interface:

```
var date = DateTime.SpecifyKind((s as UIDatePicker).Date, DateTimeKind.Local).ToLocalTime();
```

In the ValueChanged Handler I've double checked that the Locale and TimeZone is the same as what was set. The TimeZone is Europe/Dublin and Locale en_US.
This information was retrieved by:

```
datePicker.Locale.LocaleIdentifier;
datePicker.DatePicker.TimeZone;
```

Is there another step I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that daylight savings is in effect? This can sometimes cause hour differences similar to what you seem to be experiencing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The date returned from DatePicker is in UTC format. There are several methods of converting UTC to local time. As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/963812/941776) answer states ToLocalTime is the best one.

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(datePicker.Date, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer.  In the original code, the OP specified `DateTimeKind.Local` instead of `DateTimeKind.Utc`.  Since an `NSDate` represents UTC but the conversion doesn't set the `.Kind`, this is how you have to do it.

Comment: But datePicker.Date is an NSDate and the first parameter of the method DateTime.SpecifyKind is a DateTime...

Answer (score 2):

After `var date = DateTime ...`, add the following:

```
if (date.IsDaylightSavingTime ())
    date = date.AddHours (1);
```

Comment: Daylight savings time is not always adjusted by an hour. http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/  http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time-wisdom

Comment: Indeed. It's a quick fix. I'd rather be almost correct than completely wrong, so to speak. You could of course use a DST offset based on timezone. Do you have a nice proposal for this? I like the second link, but it doesn't give any answers; only states that we carry misconceptions.

Comment: The answer is in my answer below. Use DateFormatter, it takes care of DST for you.

Comment: Yes, but only when outputting as text

Comment: TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc returns DateTime.

Answer (score 2):

This magical code fixed all my problems with daylight savings and timezones. Write if you need help.

```
NSDate sourceDate = date;

NSTimeZone sourceTimeZone = new NSTimeZone ("UTC");
NSTimeZone destinationTimeZone = NSTimeZone.LocalTimeZone;

int sourceGMTOffset = sourceTimeZone.SecondsFromGMT (sourceDate);
int destinationGMTOffset = destinationTimeZone.SecondsFromGMT (sourceDate);
int interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

var destinationDate = sourceDate.AddSeconds (interval);

var dateTime = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0,0).AddSeconds(destinationDate.SecondsSinceReferenceDate);

DescriptionLabel.Text = dateTime.ToString ("dd.MM.yyyy. HH:mm");
this.date = destinationDate;
```

Comment: This code adds unnecessary complexity. If you want to convert time to your local timezone simply use DateTime.ToLocalTime().