# Display date without affecting server and local time

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

My server date and time is UTC+11:00 and my local date-time setting is +5:30, so here i get conflicts on displaying the date,i.e when i about to display the in grid it display the previous day date, but it should display the date that i had selected.

My request to server is..
[image]

My grid display **13-02-14** if i select **14-02-14**..
[image]

below screen shot is **server response**..
[image]

my coding part that takes previous date..
[image]

The date from the server should be displayed. The local timezone should not be affect the way the server date is displayed, i should display the data by setting time to 00:00:00.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.dotnetperls.com/timezone

Comment: check these answer. http://stackoverflow.com/q/179940/3184380