# Correct approach to getting the universal time zone

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, timezone

In my project I want to get the universal time zone. I used two different kinds of approaches but I don't know which one is the best practice.

First approach is

```
public static DateTime GetUniversalTime(DateTime localDateTime)
{
    TimeZone zone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
    DateTime universal = zone.ToUniversalTime(localDateTime);
    return universal;
}
```

then I want revert to local time I used the below method:

```
public static DateTime GetLocalTime(DateTime universalDateTime)
{
    TimeZone zone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
    DateTime local = zone.ToLocalTime(universalDateTime);
    return local;
}
```

and second approach is get universal time zone  `DateTime.UtcNow;`
then I want to revert to local time I used the above  `GetLocalTime` method.

Can one explain what is the  different between the above two approaches?

Which one is the best practice ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think there might be different ways to do the same thing. So those might be equivalent solutions, just one is a shortcut.

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy thanks... Have any shortcut for get local time ?

Comment: Isn't DateTime.Now the local equivalent of DateTime.UtcNow?

Comment: dateTime.ToLocalTime() is much shorter than your previous solution and gives same result I believe

Comment: @CodingKiwi when you need to get current time, then yes. But when you have time stored in DB, then it is different task

Comment: @CodingKiwi No, I stored the universal time in to database. i need to convert in to local time whenever time showing UI

Comment: Ah I see. This answer gives a different approach, although I'm not sure if it counts as neater: http://stackoverflow.com/a/963812/128386

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are asking about best practices:

- Do *not* use the `TimeZone` class.  If you need time zone conversions, use the `TimeZoneInfo` class instead.  This is very clear in [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.aspx):

  [image: MSDN]
- Whenever possible, avoid *any* use of "local" time.  It is local to the system where the code is running.  In the vast majority of real-world use cases, it is likely that it is *not* the local time zone of your user.  This is especially true in a web application.

  That means you should not be calling *any* of the following:

  - `DateTime.Now`
  - `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone`
  - `TimeZoneInfo.Local`
  - `DateTime.ToLocalTime()`
  - `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()`
  - Any other method that involves the server's local time zone.
- Instead, your application should allow the user to select a time zone, then you can convert to and from the local time *in that zone* using the `TimeZoneInfo.Convert...` methods.
- If you need the current universal time, use `DateTime.UtcNow` or `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`.
- If you need the current local time zone of your server, ONLY use `DateTimeOffset.Now`.
- If you need the current local time in a known time zone, such as US Eastern Time:

  ```
  DateTime easternNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
                                     DateTime.UtcNow, "Eastern Standard Time");
  ```
- If you want to convert between a known time zone and UTC, then use the `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc` and `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` methods, and be sure to pass in the time zone you are converting to/from:

  ```
  // get the local time zone of your user, not of the server!
  TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

  // use this to convert from UTC to local
  DateTime local = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(yourUtcDateTime, tzi);

  // use this to convert from local to UTC
  DateTime utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(yourLocalDateTime, tzi);
  ```

  Be aware that when you convert from local to UTC, you might encounter ambiguities during daylight saving time transitions.  Read more in [the DST tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).

Additional reading: [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)

Answer (score -3):

For Universal Time.

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()
```

For Local Time

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()
```

Universal To Local

```
var nowUtc = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
var nowLocal = nowUtc.ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: the question is not about that. This is one of his own solutions

Comment: I don't want new approaches. The above method is working fine but i want know whats is the different between    TimeZone and DateTime.UtcNow;

Comment: Both of them same. Because Timezone Knows hour difference Local and Universal. When your LocalTime is UTC +3 . TouniversalTime extension will subtract 3 hour from local. If you send Universal Time as paramater to GetUniversalTime funtion IT'll return equal result with parameter. Becase DataTime object stores TimezoneInfo . 

Same Logic for ToLocalTime.