# How to convert a UTC DateTimeOffset to a DateTime that uses the systems timezone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, quartz.net, datetimeoffset

Quartz.net offers a method to get the next time of the next trigger event: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/html/cc03bb79-c0c4-6d84-3d05-a17f59727c98.htm

The docs claim that this `Trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc()` method return a `DateTime?` but it actually returns a `DateTimeOffset?`. I don't really get what `DateTimeOffset` is for or why this function return one instead of a regular `DateTime`. All I want is the next time the trigger is going to run but in my timezone.

I did this `trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc().Value.DateTime` but it gave me a time 2 hours early, i.e. the UTC time. How can I get the correct time according to my computer?

Comment: Use the `LocalDateTime`. 
You should have a [look][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time

Comment: You may be interested in [DateTime vs DateTimeOffset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset).

Comment: Also, you are looking at Quartz's 1.0 docs.  Quartz 2.0 changed this method to return a `DateTimeOffset?`, [as shown here](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/html/e07a781b-39c8-db14-3421-c563497fe23c.htm).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can just use the [`DateTimeOffset.LocalDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.localdatetime) property:

```
trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc().Value.LocalDateTime
```

From the documentation:

> If necessary, the LocalDateTime property converts the current DateTimeOffset object's date and time to the local system's date and time. The conversion is a two-step operation:
>
> - The property converts the current DateTimeOffset object's time to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
> - The property then converts UTC to local time.

You should really look into `DateTimeOffset` though - it's an important type to understand if you're using the BCL for date/time work.

Comment: Why was this answer so hard to find? The M$ Docs on this are evil!!! [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset)

Answer (score 0):

I bumped to this problem and none of these was real answer (by this question title). Solution examples for question title:

```
var myDateTimeOffset = (DateTimeOffset)DateTime.UtcNow;
var ans1 = myDateTimeOffset.DateTime.ToLocalTime();
var ans2 = myDateTimeOffset.DateTime.ToLocalTime().ToLocalTime(); // ans1==ans2
```

.NET5 C# 9.0

[image]

Answer (score -2):

This code is to convert utc to local

```
var local = utc.ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: That's *just* going to change the `DateTime`'s kind, without changing its value at all. If the OP is simply displaying the value, then they wont see any change

Comment: The OP is indeed simply displaying the value