# specifying CultureInfo in isDate() or Datetime.TryParse

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, date-format, cultureinfo

I need to identify if a string is a date in format `dd.mm.yyyy`.

However the application is running on systems with different language settings. Thus using `isDate` or `TryParse` on a 'valid' string returns true on a german system (since those functions use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`) and return false on a system with i.e. english system settings.

Is there a function that checks if a string is a valid date with respect to a specified CultureInfo?

Of course i can always use regex to verify this, but i can't imagine that this is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the format of the string and this won't change you should use `DateTime.TryParseExact` using the `InvariantCulture`

```
Imports System.Globalization

Dim dateString As String = "31.12.1901"
Dim dateValue As Date
Dim dateFormat As String = "dd.MM.yyyy"

If DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dateValue) Then
    'In the format expected
Else
    'NOT in the format expected
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like i missed an overload of the TryParse Method:

```
Dim myculture As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
myculture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"
myculture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"

If DateTime.TryParse("27/10/2010", myculture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, New DateTime) Then

'Currect Date

End If
```

works perfectly fine. (See http://forums.asp.net/t/1443698.aspx?in+ASP+NET+vb+IsDate+function+is+working+wrongly+ for details)

Comment: You need to use InvariantCulture or else this won't work as you expect it to

Comment: I think i am missunderstanding since the InvariantCulture depends on the english language, doesn't it? Thus i cannot pass InvariantCulture and still get the desired result? Still - the code above is just a general example taken from the link i provided. In my app i am passing a dedicated CultureInfo object which is used in several places.

Comment: No the Invariant culture is essentially *no* specific culture or language.

Comment: You really want to do it per @MattWilko's answer. First, because of the Invariant culture thing; but also because `TryParse` tends to be orders of magnitude slower than `TryParseExact` -- see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time/7905548#7905548) for details.