# auto refresh windows form in specific time c#

Tags: c#

Hello I do this code for does this statement ( `MessageBox.Show("done ");`) when the time is between 11:47 , 11:49

```
public Form1()
{   
    InitializeComponent();
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer MyTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    MyTimer.Interval = (1 * 60 *500 ); // 1 mins
    MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(times);
    MyTimer.Start();

}

private void times(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime t1 = DateTime.Parse("11:47:00.000");
    DateTime t2 = DateTime.Parse("11:49:00.000");
    TimeSpan now = DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay;
    if (t1.TimeOfDay <= now && t2.TimeOfDay >= now)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("done ");
}
```

but it doesn't working

Comment: Does it even get into the `MyTimer_Tick method`? Because in handler you have different method in the constructor - this `+=new EventHandler(times)` should be rather `+= MyTimer_Tick`.

Comment: To solve your mistery just [read this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time)

Comment: if i try to write into "times" this statement ( MessageBox.Show("done ");)
it work, but if i try to write all these statement it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created DateTime and Timespan, where DateTime is a point in time and TimeSpan is an interval between two points in time.

Also a second has 1000 milliseconds, so better use:

```
    MyTimer.Interval = (1 * 60 * 1000); // 1 mins
```

Try this:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Windows.Forms.Timer MyTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        MyTimer.Interval = (1 * 60 * 1000); // 1 mins
        MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(times);
        MyTimer.Start();
    }

    private void times(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime t1 = DateTime.Parse("11:47:00.000");
        DateTime t2 = DateTime.Parse("11:50:00.000");
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        if (t1 <= now && t2 >= now)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("done ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to make it trigger at 11:48...

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer MyTimer;
    private TimeSpan TargetTime = new TimeSpan(11, 48, 0);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        MyTimer.Interval = (int)MillisecondsToTargetTime(TargetTime);
        MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(times);
        MyTimer.Start();
    }

    private double MillisecondsToTargetTime(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Add(ts);
        if (DateTime.Now > dt)
        {
            dt = dt.AddDays(1);
        }
        return dt.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    private void times(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyTimer.Stop();

        MessageBox.Show("It's " + TargetTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm"));

        MyTimer.Interval = (int)MillisecondsToTargetTime(TargetTime);
        MyTimer.Start();
    }
```