# Convert string with date & UTC offset to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, utc, timezone-offset

I am trying to parse a string `"20160918000500 +0200"` to `DateTime` containing offset value `"+0200"`.

I tried the following but it gives invalid `DateTime` exception.

```
DateTime dtDateTime = DateTime.Parse("20160918000500 +0200",new CultureInfo("yyyyMMddHHmmss zzz"));
```

Is there a way to convert the `String` exactly to `Datetime` with `UTC offset value`?

Comment: Check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time

Answer (score 1):

To preserve your Offset, use the [`DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.parseexact.aspx) method:

```
string str = "20160918000500 +0200";
var result = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddHHmmss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try out one of [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) methods of DateTime class

Comment: It would be better to parse `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` since string contains UTF Offset part.