# Easiest way to convert GMT date to DateTime object

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am getting GMT DateTime as string input. For example

```
SampleDate = "20170221T085258.732 GMT"
```

Now, I want to convert this to datetime object. What is the best way of doing this conversion?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time#963812

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact() with suitable format string?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use ToLocalTime() Then you can change it to whatever timezone you care about.

```
 DateTimeOffset.Parse(SampleDate).ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: *I am getting GMT DateTime as string input* - `SampleDate` is a string, not a `DateTime` type

Comment: sorry, spoke to fast, use datetimeoffset first, then you can do localtime to get it to your timezone if you need to.

Comment: I tried this earlier, getting "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

To remove the GMT and time zone, change the following line:

```
document.write(d.toString().replace(/GMT.*/g,""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this code using `DateTime.ParseExact()`

```
 string SampleDate=""20170221T085258.732 GMT";  
 DateTime dateObject = DateTime.ParseExact(SampleDate,"ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz",  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For more info heres the link for `DateTime.ParseExact`  MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me. Date contain some unwanted characters like "T",".","GMT" , once I removed those, it started working..

But I feel that, there has to be some better solution for this.

```
    //I can write a regular expression to keep only numeric values and avoid this replacements...
    SampleDate = "20170221T085258.732 GMT"
    SampleDate = SampleDate.Replace("GMT", "")
    SampleDate = SampleDate.Replace("T", "")
    SampleDate = SampleDate.Replace(".", "")

    Dim dateObject As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(SampleDate.Trim(), "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: You should edit your question to include this information and then delete this answer.  If you do this, there is a chance that the question may be re-opened, but I suspect that it will be marked as a duplicate.  Also, your conversion will only be accurate if the computer executing the code is configured as being in the GMT timezone.