# Cannot translate date in current locale

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I'm trying to translate a `Date` in the current system language, this is my date: `2018/01/01`, I tried to achieve my goal in this way:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2018/01/01", "dddd MMMM yyyy", new CultureInfo("it-IT")).ToString();
```

unfortunately I get:

> System.ArgumentNullException

The `InnerException` say:

> String not recognized as a valid DateTime value.

I used `ParseExact` to avoid this error, what I did wrong?

Comment: Is it-IT language pack installed on your system?

Comment: does it's help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time  ?

Comment: @hustlecoder yes, my system is italian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code it will work.

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2018/01/01", "yyyy/MM/dd", new CultureInfo("it-IT"));
```

I think you now know the error reason.
Thanks

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Please copy and paste the code, it works for me!

Comment: thanks, and happy 2018!

Comment: You too bro.Thanks.