# parse string UTC time back to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, time

I´m trying to parse string UTC time back to DateTime. Any idea? I´m out of ideas :D.

```
  private static DataTable FinishFormating(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        DataColumnCollection columns = dataTable.Columns;

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            if (columns.Contains("InUseSince"))
            {
                row["InUseSince"].ToString();
                //2019-09-20T00:00:00+02:00
                //    string str = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff'Z'");
                DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(row[4].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.s+zzzzzz",
                                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert UTC/GMT time to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time)

Comment: I better think once more before i asked.                   //  string str = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzzzzz");

Comment: I just generated same string with editing that.

Comment: Then I know what is format

Comment: always the same :D

Answer (score 0):

I better think once more guys.. :D

Just troubleshoot it with that line until you get wanted format.

string str = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzzzzz");

usefull page for that
https://support.travelport.com/webhelp/uapi/Content/Getting_Started/Design_Considerations/Date_and_Time_Formats.htm